# Parametric plot from the results of NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I'm having a bit of trouble making a `ParametricPlot` from two curves, At fisrt I was having difficulty solving my systems of autonomous ODEs, but then finally got a way to solve it. However, I am now not able to figure out how to get the parametric plot.

```
solution[t_] = 
  With[{n = 1.5}, 
    NDSolve[
      {q'[t] == 
         ((q[t]^2)/3)*(3 - n)*x[t]^2 - ((q[t]^2)/3)*n*(y[t] - 1) - ((q[t]^2)/3) + (q[t]*x[t]/3)*(3 - n)*x[t]^2 - (q[t]*x[t]/3)*n*(y[t] - 1) + (q[t]*x[t]/3) + (1/3)*x[t]^2 - (1/3) + (1/3)*((n*y[t]/(n - 1))), 
       y'[t] == 
         ((2*y[t]*x[t]^2)/3)*(3 - n)*(x[t] + q[t]) + (2*x[t]*y[t]/3)*((n^2 - 2*n + 2)/(n - 1)) - (2*x[t]*y[t]/3)*n*y[t] + (2*q[t]*n*y[t]*((1 - y[t])/3)), 
       x'[t] == 
         ((x[t]^3)/3)*(3 - n)*(q[t] + x[t]) + ((x[t]^2)/3)*n*(2 - y[t]) - 5*((x[t]^2)/3) + (q[t]*x[t]/3)* n*(1 - y[t]) - (q[t]*x[t]) + (1/3)*((n*(n - 2)*y[t])/(n - 1)) - (1/3)*n + 2/3, 
       q[0] == -1.33, y[0] == 0.88, x[0] == 0.33}, 
      {q[t], y[t],  x[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]][[1, All, 2]]

Plot[solution[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

I want to get a parametric plot of `q[t]` and `y[t]`. And eventually a 3D plot of `q[t], y[t], x[t]`.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are facing is to correctly call out the desired dependent variables. So, you need to specify the position of the output. For example, you want to have `q[x]` then you need to use `solution[t][[1]]`.

For parametric plot, try this out,

```
ParametricPlot[{solution[t][[1]], solution[t][[2]]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

and then for 3D

```
ParametricPlot3D[{solution[t][[1]], solution[t][[2]], solution[t][[3]]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Redefine your solution a little bit to

```
solution := 
With[{n = 1.5}, 
NDSolve[{q'[t] == ((q[t]^2)/3)*(3 - n)*x[t]^2 - ((q[t]^2)/3)*
   n*(y[t] - 1) - ((q[t]^2)/3) + (q[t]*x[t]/3)*(3 - n)*
   x[t]^2 - (q[t]*x[t]/3)*n*(y[t] - 1) + (q[t]*x[t]/3) + (1/3)*
   x[t]^2 - (1/3) + (1/3)*((n*y[t]/(n - 1))), 
y'[t] == ((2*y[t]*x[t]^2)/3)*(3 - n)*(x[t] + q[t]) + (2*x[t]*
     y[t]/3)*((n^2 - 2*n + 2)/(n - 1)) - (2*x[t]*y[t]/3)*n*
   y[t] + (2*q[t]*n*y[t]*((1 - y[t])/3)), 
x'[t] == ((x[t]^3)/3)*(3 - n)*(q[t] + x[t]) + ((x[t]^2)/3)*
   n*(2 - y[t]) - 
  5*((x[t]^2)/3) + (q[t]*x[t]/3)*
   n*(1 - y[t]) - (q[t]*
    x[t]) + (1/3)*((n*(n - 2)*y[t])/(n - 1)) - (1/3)*n + 2/3, 
q[0] == -1.33, y[0] == 0.88, x[0] == 0.33}, {q , y , x }, {t, 0, 
10}]] [[1]]
```

Now you can plot your results

```
Plot[Evaluate[ {q[t], y[t]} /. solution ], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the assist!